# How to pass multiple group_by arguments to a dplyr join function?

Tags: r, function, dplyr, left-join

I have tried the example below to pass multiple keys in a dplyr join function but it is not working.

```
data("mtcars")

library(tidyverse)

function_left_join <- function(...) {
  
  mtcars %>% 
    left_join(mtcars, by = names(select(., {{...}})))
  
}

head(function_left_join(mpg, cyl))
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case it is not necessray to "embrace" the `...`:

```r
library(dplyr)

function_left_join <- function(...) {
  
  mtcars %>% left_join(mtcars, by = names(select(., ...)))
  
}

head(function_left_join(mpg, cyl))
#>    mpg cyl disp.x hp.x drat.x  wt.x qsec.x vs.x am.x gear.x carb.x disp.y hp.y
#> 1 21.0   6    160  110   3.90 2.620  16.46    0    1      4      4  160.0  110
#> 2 21.0   6    160  110   3.90 2.620  16.46    0    1      4      4  160.0  110
#> 3 21.0   6    160  110   3.90 2.875  17.02    0    1      4      4  160.0  110
#> 4 21.0   6    160  110   3.90 2.875  17.02    0    1      4      4  160.0  110
#> 5 22.8   4    108   93   3.85 2.320  18.61    1    1      4      1  108.0   93
#> 6 22.8   4    108   93   3.85 2.320  18.61    1    1      4      1  140.8   95
#>   drat.y  wt.y qsec.y vs.y am.y gear.y carb.y
#> 1   3.90 2.620  16.46    0    1      4      4
#> 2   3.90 2.875  17.02    0    1      4      4
#> 3   3.90 2.620  16.46    0    1      4      4
#> 4   3.90 2.875  17.02    0    1      4      4
#> 5   3.85 2.320  18.61    1    1      4      1
#> 6   3.92 3.150  22.90    1    0      4      2
```